# How can I add a badge to a tab in CodenameOne?

Tags: codenameone

I tried this code:

```
FloatingActionButton badge = FloatingActionButton.createBadge("33");
badge.bindFabToContainer(tabs.getTabComponentAt(3), Component.RIGHT, Component.TOP);
```

However for some reason I get a

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Component is already contained in Container

exception.

I tried also:

```
tabs.getTabsContainer().getComponentAt(3)
```

without success.

Answer (score 0):

Bind creates a new container that should be added instead of the component. This won't work for a case like tabs where the button be added when you add a tab component. You are also relying on internal behavior of looking up a specific tab which is pretty fragile to begin with.

You can use the approach listed [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-customize-tabs-behavior.html) which shows how you can create a completely custom component to represent a tab.